# Extremum - relationship between cartesian and polar coordinates

Tags: real-analysis

If I find local minimum or maximum of function in polar coordinates, can I say that it is the same as in cartesian coordinates ?

Comment: Does "it" refer to the _extreme value_ ("yes") or to the _coordinates of the extremum_ (generally "no")?

Comment: We have function $z = f(x,y)$ and I want to compute local extrema. Can we just use polar coordinates, find local extrema, and then return them to cartesian coordinates ?

Comment: Finding an extremum in polar coordinates and converting to Cartesian does give the location of the extremum in Cartesian, yes. (You might consider editing the question for posterity; your intended meaning (which is fairly clear in your comment) is distinct from both ways in which I read your question as originally worded. (Incidentally, I didn't downvote.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definition: $x$ is a local maximum for $f$ if there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that:

$$\forall y \in U:~f\left(y\right)\leq f\left(x\right)$$

Does this look coordinate-dependent?

For definitions look [here](http://planetmath.org/extremum).